# Conjecture of relation between residues of Feynman integrals and mixed Tate motives

Tags: motives, quantum-field-theory, tannakian-category, feynman-integral, virtual-motives

In many articles (for example in articles given by M.Marcoli) there is statement that there is the following conjecture

> Residues of Feynman integrals in scalar field theories are always periods of mixed Tate motives

I have three questions related to this conjecture

1) What is the recent knowledge of this conjecture ? Is it proven or partially proven ? (Articles which I read have at least five/six years).

2) One of the supporting evidence were [computations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9609128v3.pdf) collected by Broadhurst and Kreimer. Where can I found more actual data (if such exist) ?

3) Is it a generalization of this conjecture on bosonic/fermionic field theories ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) Counterexamples were found in the paper Brown, Francis; Schnetz, Oliver:
"A $K3$ in $\phi^4$". Duke Math. J. 161 (2012), no. 10, 1817–1862. It is now the general feeling that most $\phi^4$-Feynman integrals are not mixed Tate.

2) In 2008, Schnetz has compiled a list of Feynman integrals in [Quantum periods: A census of $\phi^4$-transcendentals](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.2856). These were obtained using numerical computations. Meanwhile, for all results rigorous proofs have been found.

3) No clue.